# Reactjs vite-plugin-federation import component dynamicly not working

Tags: reactjs, vite, dynamic-import

I want to use vite federation to build a micro-frontend structure. However, host website will get error when trying to import the remote components dynamicly.

I Would like to ask how can I resolve this problem?

```
Used plugin: @originjs/vite-plugin-federation: v1.2.3
             react: v18.2.0
```

host application vite.config.ts file:

```
/// <reference types="vitest" />
/// <reference types="vite/client" />

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'url'

import federation from '@originjs/vite-plugin-federation'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(),
  federation({
    name: "app",
    remotes: {
      giris: "http://localhost:7001/giris/assets/remoteEntry.js"
    },
    shared: ["react", "react-dom"]
  })],
  base: "/",
  envDir: './src/environments/',
  server: {
    port: 7000
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      // @ts-ignore
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
  build: {
    modulePreload: false,
    target: "esnext",
    minify: false,
    cssCodeSplit: false
  }
})
```

host application Load.tsx file static import version. This is working:

```
import React, { Component, ReactNode, Suspense } from 'react';
import HomePageGiris from "giris/HomePage";
interface IProps {}

class Load extends Component<IProps> {

    render(): ReactNode {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
               <HomePageGiris/>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
};

export default Load;
```

host application Load.tsx file dynamic import version. This is not working:

```
import React, { Component, ReactNode, Suspense } from 'react';
import HomePageGiris from "giris/HomePage";
interface IProps {}

const GetHome = (pageCode: string): JSX.Element => {
     const Componentz = React.lazy(() => import(`${pageCode}/HomePage`));
     return <Suspense fallback={<h1>Loading...</h1>}><Componentz /></Suspense>
}

class Load extends Component<IProps> {

    render(): ReactNode {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {GetHome("giris")} 
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
};

export default Load;
```

Error is:

```
6 |  import React, { Component, Suspense } from "react";
17 |  const GetHome = (pageCode) => {
18 |    const Componentz = React.lazy(() => import(`${pageCode}/HomePage`));
   |                                               ^
19 |    return /* @__PURE__ */ jsxDEV(Suspense, { fallback: /* @__PURE__ */ jsxDEV("h1", { children: "Loading..." }, void 0, false, {
20 |      fileName: "C:/myapp/main-app/src/components/middle/tab/Load.tsx",
The above dynamic import cannot be analyzed by Vite.
See https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/dynamic-import-vars#limitations for supported dynamic import formats. If this is intended to be left as-is, you can use the /* @vite-ignore */ comment inside the import() call to suppress this warning.

  Plugin: vite:import-analysis
  File: C:/myapp/main-app/src/components/middle/tab/Load.tsx
```

Thanks